# When is Polymorphic not advisable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'll provide three scenarios and how I see them all working without Polymorphic.

#### Scenario #1

```
Event has_one :address # Event keeps child reference Address_id
Profile has_one :address # Profile keeps child reference Address_id
# Address doesn't keep any parent references in this example.
```

#### Scenario #2

```
Event has_one :phone # Event keeps child reference phone_id
Profile has_many :phones # Phones can keep parent profile_id as an optional field.
# Optional because it may belong to event.
```

#### Scenario #3

```
User has_many :contacts # Contacts keeps parent reference user_id
User has_many :issues # Issues keeps parent reference user_id
# There are no child references here
```

As I see it, each of these scenarios work without Polymorphism in the equation.  Is Polymorphic important here?  And what are the trade-offs?

Does direction of reference effect dependent deletion of child entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use polymorphism when a model can belong_to more than one other model type.

The disadvantages with your scenarios:

1) This may work since it is a has_one, but is inflexible if you want to move to has_many. Also, when the address is destroyed you're left with a dangling address_id in an Event or Profile. Bad news. You'd have to manage this manually, which is unnecessary and error-prone. I'd use polymorphism here.

2) This simply feels sketchy to me. Why mix belongs_to and has_one association type on the Phone model. That's just asking for bugs. I'd use polymorphism here.

3) Because this is a User having many other things, polymorphism is not needed here. This is a pretty straight-forward relationship. Don't use polymorphism here.

Comment: Do you recommend using has_one address as addressable?  Or even with just one should I use has_many?

Comment: no just use has_one. You can always adjust later if you need to.